# How do you run a setup.py file properly?

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy

I'm trying to run this setup.py file, which was in a .tat.gz file. I'm going to the directory it's in and running *python setup.py* but get this error message:

```
brandon@brandon-NV57H:~/Downloads/numpy-1.9.2$ python setup.py
Running from numpy source directory.
/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py:267: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'test_suite'
  warnings.warn(msg)
usage: setup.py [global_opts] cmd1 [cmd1_opts] [cmd2 [cmd2_opts] ...]
   or: setup.py --help [cmd1 cmd2 ...]
   or: setup.py --help-commands
   or: setup.py cmd --help

error: no commands supplied
brandon@brandon-NV57H:~/Downloads/numpy-1.9.2$
```

Can anyone help me out? How do I fix this? I have both python2.7 and python3.4.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

If you want to install it then the command is `install`:

```
python setup.py install
```

If you need to build the package first, use the `build` command before installing:

```
python setup.py build
```

Hope this helps!