# Installing scrapinghub splash in windows cmd

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy, scrapy-splash

I'm new to using scrapy / splash. Based on the instructions [here](https://github.com/scrapy-plugins/scrapy-splash) I have successfully installed scrapy-splash. The second requirement is splash itself. I do not have docker and [splash documentation](http://splash.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html) does not have instructions on how to install splash for windows without docker. Could someone please help?

This is the error msg i get

```
C:\splash>C:\Python27\Python.exe setup.py
usage: setup.py [global_opts] cmd1 [cmd1_opts] [cmd2 [cmd2_opts] ...]
   or: setup.py --help [cmd1 cmd2 ...]
   or: setup.py --help-commands
   or: setup.py cmd --help

error: no commands supplied
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There are no instructions on how to install Splash without Docker on Windows because it is complicated and requires a lot of dependencies; Docker is easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found my answer here: [How do you run a setup.py file properly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31373797/how-do-you-run-a-setup-py-file-properly)

```
C:\Python27\Python.exe setup.py install
```

Answer (score 1):

scrapy-splash needs a docker as its virtual environment. 
Therefore it is so hard to deploy splash without docker.