# DistutilsArgError: no commands supplied

Tags: python, reinforcement-learning, setup.py

I am trying to import this package (https://github.com/kandouss/marlgrid) in my script, by doing the following:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(
    name="marlgrid",
    version="0.0.5",
    packages=find_packages(),
    install_requires=["numpy", "tqdm", "gym", "gym-minigrid", "numba"],
)

import numpy as np
import marlgrid

from marlgrid.rendering import InteractivePlayerWindow
from marlgrid.agents import GridAgentInterface
from marlgrid.envs import env_from_config
```

However, I receive this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\bolot\anaconda3\lib\distutils\core.py", line 134, in setup
    ok = dist.parse_command_line()

  File "C:\Users\bolot\anaconda3\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 501, in parse_command_line
    raise DistutilsArgError("no commands supplied")

DistutilsArgError: no commands supplied


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

SystemExit: usage: temp.py [global_opts] cmd1 [cmd1_opts] [cmd2 [cmd2_opts] ...]
   or: temp.py --help [cmd1 cmd2 ...]
   or: temp.py --help-commands
   or: temp.py cmd --help

error: no commands supplied
```

Could you please help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Run your script from the command-line as `python setup.py install`

Note if you need to build first, run `python setup.py build`

###### Sources:

[How do you run a setup.py file properly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31373797/how-do-you-run-a-setup-py-file-properly)

[How to avoid a "No commands supplied" on setup.py with py.test](https://superuser.com/questions/222957/no-commands-supplied-error-when-executing-a-python-script-on-ubuntu/222958)

Comment: I have cloned the repo and run the script as `python setup.py install`, but I'm still having the same error.